# Delete item from Multiple file Object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking the data from the file input to an object in jQuery. I am able to pass the data to `PHP` and manage from there.

Now I am trying to delete a single file programatically from jQuery.

The purpose is, I am showing the file name in UI once selected and the user has the option to delete selected file from there.

I tried using Javascript delete function for this like `delete object[index]`. But it is not working.

Is it possible to delete file from this object? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The files are stored on the element in a FileList that you can access with:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files;
```

But it is read-only so you cannot alter it in any way.
On the other hand you can add an attribute "accept" to the input element, with a list of mime-types (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file), which can act as a filter to begin with, like this:

```
<input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
```